# Winform Return Result

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to check if the actions have done by a `winform`, were done successfully.

```
MainForm form = new MainForm();
form.Show();
//continue in case the form returns true
```

How can I return and check the value after the winform is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `DialogResult` for that:

```
MainForm form = new MainForm();
DialogResult result = form.ShowDialog();

if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
}
else
{
}
```

You have to set the `DialogResult` of the form, for example using a button `Click` event handler:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What should I do in the form in order to set the dialog result to OK?

Comment: Thanks. Why can't I use the `form.Show` method?

Comment: Because the `Show` doesn't wait until there is a result from the `Form`. It continues execution in two branches. Hence, you don't have a result.

Comment: So when the usage of `Show` is better than `ShowDialog`?

Comment: When you want to wait for the result of the `Form`.

Comment: In case I wait for result I use the `showDialog` . When it is necessary to use the 'show'?

Comment: When the execution of the code following is not depending on the result of the form and can be shown side to side with the form you are opening.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `form.Show()` returns immediately. You user will have no chance to do anything before the call returns. If you want to wait until the user presses a button like OK or Cancel you need to call [form.ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that will block the execution of the remainder of your code until the closing of the form.

```
 using(MainForm form = new MainForm())
 {
      DialogResult dr = form.ShowDialog();
      if(dr == DialogResult.OK)
      {
         // User presses OK button, 
         // read the public property UserName and 
         // appply your logic here.
         string userName = form.UserName;

      }
      else if(dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
      {
         // User presses Cancel button
         MessageBox.Show("Login aborted");
      }
}
```

This code requires also some property settings on the MainForm class buttons. The OK button should have its property [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) set to the enum DialogResult.OK while the Cancel button should have its property set to DialogResult.Cancel

In this way, when your user presses the OK/Cancel button your MainForm will be hidden (still not closed and/or disposed) and you can access the public properties of the MainForm instance from the using block.

For example, suppose that the OK button event handler contains a login validation of your username

```
private void cmdOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(.....some kind of authentication method....)
    {
        this.UserName = "Steve";
        ....
    }
}
```

and the MainForm class, a public property called UserName

```
public string UserName {get; private set}
```

Now, as shown in the example above, you could retrieve the UserName property inside the using block

Notice that the using block around the call to the creation of the form instance will ensure a proper disposing of the form at the closing brace.